# Watch (rotating) log in screen

Tags: debian, gnu-screen, syslog, logrotate, debian-stretch

I'm running a mailserver which I connect to using SSH. My `.bash_profile` is configured to attatch a SSH session to a certain `screen` session.

Now I'd like to have a log (e.g. the syslog) printed to one window of this screen session. I tried running

```
tail -f /var/log/syslog
```

but the output stops every day at 6:25. I guess that that is the time when the log gets rotated. So is there a way to have the log printed so screen?

Answer (score 1):

You need `tail --follow=name /var/log/syslog`

The reason is that by default—supposedly for performance reason—`tail`
opens the specified file and then watches *the file descriptor* it obtains
from that `open(2)` call for changes.
This works okay for as long the file is changed—appended to or even rewritten (by truncating it first) but it stops working if the file is *replaced*—that is, removed and created with the same name, and that's what `logrotate` typically does.

The "name" mode of `--follow` makes `tail` use a more costly `stat(2)` syscall which actually "resolves" the file's name each time via the filesystem layer, and if `tail` notices the file changed its so-called ["inode"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inode), `tail` re-opens the file.

The output from `man tail`:

> `-f, --follow[={name|descriptor}]`
>
> output appended data as the file grows;
>   an absent option argument means 'descriptor'

You may also look at the `-F` command-line option, which is defined as

> `-F` same as `--follow=name --retry`

Answer (score 0):

Your guess is actually correct. At this time syslog interrupt write on the log, make a gz of it and re-start log of it.

You could try with

```
tail -f --retry /var/log/syslog
```

This way tail should retry to re-open the file when log-rotation has been done